# ORACLE - remove from result set if two or more "same" records found

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID | NAME  | REFERENCE | STATUS
-------------------------------
 1 | name1 | 123       | 0     
 2 | name1 | 123       | 1     
 3 | name2 | 111       | 0     
 4 | name3 | 222       | 0     
 5 | name5 | 555       | 1
```

Let's say I have this table TABLE1. I need a select statement that will only find records with STATUS=0, but if "same" record exists with STATUS=1 (like those records with ID 1 and 2)

So, query must find only third and fourth record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your suggested results, I am reading your question as "find only records with status = 0 where the same name/reference combination doesn't have a record with status = 1".

One way you can do this is with a `not exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where status = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.reference = t.reference and             
                        t2.status = 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query out:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 B ON
A.ID = B.ID AND
A.NAME = B.NAME AND
A.REFERENCE = B.REFERENCE AND 
B.STATUS = 1
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
AND B.REFERENCE IS NULL
```

The NULL check on B.REFERENCE in the WHERE clause basically ensures that there was no matching record found in the LEFT JOIN (you could just use B.ID or B.NAME also).

Answer (score 0):

`MINUS` can be used to get the value with Status both 0 but not 1.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Reference, Status 
FROM   Table1
WHERE  (Name, Reference) IN (SELECT Name, Reference
                             FROM   Table1
                             WHERE  Status = 0
                             MINUS
                             SELECT Name, Reference
                             FROM   Table1
                             WHERE  Status = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME NOT IN
          (
           SELECT NAME FROM 
           TABLE 
           GROUP BY NAME
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS)>1
          ) AND STATUS='0';
```